# Why does my discord.py bot have no commands when used cross server?

Tags: discord, discord.py

for some reason, on one server the bot works **AND** has commands on one server, and in another it is basically useless.

[server where bot is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLkvQ.png)

[server where bot works. the original server I added the bot in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OTE6.png)

I don't think that this is a issue in my code, and console returns no errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. Images of errors or code don't help us help you. "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"

Answer (score 0):

In one server the bot has a role and thus perms, in the other one it doesn't. (Or at least it doesn't seem like it). A command will not show up unless the both the user AND the bot have sufficient perms.

Comment: this is not the issue